# Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) deleting active directory account

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm working on an windows C# application which is capable of deleting Active Directory accounts. The application is running as administrator on the production server. A scheduled task run it every 15 minutes.

I get this error sometimes:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

For example: Last delete task, has successfully removed 115 account but has not managed to remove 2 account, 3 deletion attempt for each account.

I have this error only when i try to delete certain account.
It is working the majority of the time but I have no clue why it does that sometimes.

Comment: What user account is the application running as, and what permissions does it have? Are you running it from F5 in Visual Studio or from the .exe?

Comment: The application is running as administrator on the production server. A scheduled task run it every 15 minutes.

Comment: Does it only remove users from one place in AD or from a range of containers?

Comment: It remove users from one place in AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Administrator on the production server": Is it administrator on that server? Or domain administrator?

If it's domain administrator, take a look in Active Directory Users and Computers at one of the problem accounts. There is a checkbox on the Object tab called 'Prevent object from accidental deletion'. Make sure that's not checked.

I'm pretty sure that checkbox just adds a 'Deny' permission in the account permissions. If that checkbox is not checked, look anyway at the security permissions for the account. Look for any 'Deny' permissions. Deny will take precedence over Allow.

Comment: Thank you, you were right, all account have 'Prevent object from accidental deletion' checked.